# Changing the dimension of css sprite sheet

Tags: html, css

I need to add some new icons in the existing sprite image which has no vacant space left. Is adding some extra space at right side of the image by editing the image using image editor which alter the width of the image affects existing css positions in anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you are referencing positions to the sprite in already-existing CSS, and how you expand the image.

If you have an image like:

```
#myImg{background:url(/mySprite.png) top right}
```

...then if you've expanded the sprite to the right, the above code will be wrong.

Percentage references will also be problematic.

If, however all your CSS references use the left-edge with pixels, then expanding to the right is not a problem.